It promises to be an exciting few days

It promises to be an exciting few days.

The sentence above is combined with an+ exciting + few days
Is this sentence idiomatic or wrong in grammar?
What about this version: It promises to be exciting few days.

We don't do find and correct errors, here. But it's fine.

@Lambie Do you think it's better to omit 'an': It promises to be exciting few days

No, that would be a mistake. A funny three years. A serious five months. It's like a period of time. A + adjective + time period.

An belongs to exciting alone, and not to "few days."

I was trying to explain that "a three years" is not right. Nor is just: exciting few days.  For it to be idiomatic, you need a + an adjective before the time period. A good many years, an exciting three months, a formidable year, a wonderful epoch, a grilling two weeks.  You need the a as it's like a single unit.

@ishtar Not sure of your question. It's "an exciting day" and "an exciting (period of a) few days." Either way, the word exciting takes an. Few days here means maybe 3-5 days rather than very few.

@all Is it okay to write: It promises to be exciting a few days ?

I agree with @Lambie.  We are talking about a period or a group of days.  (This sounds a bit like the Periodic table:)

@gomadeng I gave you the pattern and already told you. an exciting few days. Why are you asking the same thing again?

@ishtar I wouldn't use An very bright orange just because orange starts with a vowel. That's all I meant.


It promises to be an exciting few days.

The construction: a/an + adjective + number + plural noun is both grammatical and idiomatic.
Here are some other examples:

We spent a wonderful five days at Cornwall.
She lived to a staggering 115 years

The number needn't refer to a period of time it could be any noun. Also,
if the adjective before the noun begins with a vowel, we use "an":

He owned an amazing twenty antique cars.
You have an incredible number of books in your study.

If the adjective begins with a consonant, we use "a"

I used to weigh a shocking 250lbs
In 2024, Patrick Bertoletti ate a mind-boggling 58 hot dogs in ten minutes.

Omitting the indefinite article as in the OP's suggestion “It promises to be exciting few days.” makes the sentence ungrammatical and odd-sounding, albeit comprehensible.


It promises to be an exciting few days.

The sentence is fine; few days is considered as a group and is hence singular.  The adjective modifies the group.

It promises to be exciting few days.

Your proposed version isn’t great.  You may consider
It promises to be a few exciting days.
Now the adjective modifies the days individually.
The article a before few tells us the occasion is positive; it would be negative without the article and would not be the intention.

"a few(positive) + exciting days" makes sense.
